# How to install glibc and glibcxx on Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu, visual-studio-code, glibc

I want to install **GLIBC** and **GLIBCXX** as they are mentioned as "Additional requierements" to install Visual Studio Code.

As stated in the title, I'm using Lubuntu 20.04

When search about it, I do not find anything clear. In general, when I search how to install something the answer is `sudo apt-get install package-name`, but not in this case. I've read it can be quite a sensible installation and cause a lot of trouble if not done correctly.

So, which is the correct way of installing these two packages?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why "*not in this case*?" Are saying that you cannot find the package? Or that you encounter an error? Or something else?

Comment: I mean that I just cannot find any online post that explains in a straight forward manner how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've already installed `build-essential`, then you're probably already at or beyond the requirements. To check your current `glibc` version, run this:

```
ldd --version
```

For `glibcxx`, run this (it's part of the `libstdc++6` package):

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I already have them installed in the system.